# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS wireless (suddenly) not working

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, lts, iwlwifi

Suddenly my wireless connection stopped working. Please find the contents of my wireless-info.txt file on this link:

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12367337/

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You may need to know that Wi-Fi Networks disconnected is grayed out...

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "11n_disable=1 swcrypto=1 power_save=0 bt_coex_active=0"
```

and reboot.

And also I suggest upgrading the kernel by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but that did not help. You may need to know that Wi-Fi Networks disconnected is grayed out...

Comment: Just noticed it should write "disable". Right?

Comment: Yes, there was that minor typo that changed the command! And it worked like a charm!

Thank you so much!

Comment: @TheodoreGoutas Fixed the typo.

Comment: After relaunching my web browser the computer lost its wireless connection again. Entered the command in terminal again, restarted but this time it won't connect.

What is the problem now?

Comment: @TheodoreGoutas I updated the command. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

The `dmesg` output at the end of your file shows that the firmware on your Intel card is no longer working properly. I've had an Intel card that died recently and showed the same behavior.

It's a hardware fault, you will need to replace the wlan card.